# How to use $navigateTo() in nativescript vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, vue-component, nativescript-vue

Why $navigateTo(Page) isn’t working?

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=925KhQ&v=1

Comment: You need to add your code _into_ the post itself, not as an external link. External links can become invalid in the future, rendering this post useless to future readers. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Your `pageTwo.vue` doesn't actually have a `Page`, it just has a `Label`. Your root element should be a `Page` in order for navigation to work.

Comment: Another thing is that it appears the `alert` blocks navigation. you also need to remove the alert from the function or move it to the `.then` in the alert.